# Make mouse-2 yank in org headlines

Tags: org-mode, mouse

I use `mouse-2` quite often for `mouse-yank-primary`. However, if I am at the start of an org-mode headline, instead of yanking from my cut buffer, it toggles the level of the headline. For example, if I have the cursor at the start of a level 1 headline(`|` used to represent cursor):

```
* |
```

Press `mouse-2` and it becomes:

```
** |
```

...instead of yanking the text I want as the headline. Then if I press `mouse-2` again, it becomes a level 1 headline again, and will keep toggling between the two on subsequent presses. How can I change this behavior to yank instead of changing the headline level? Normally I can figure these things out on my own, but I have had trouble in the past when it comes to changing the behavior of mouse buttons.

## Update:

I tried `describe-key` before asking this question, and it seemed like `mouse-2` should do what I want, but I just noticed at the bottom of the `describe-key` description for the`up-event` it says:

> `<mouse-2>` at that spot runs the command (lambda (e) (interactive "e")
>   (mouse-set-point e) (org-cycle)), which is an interactive Lisp function.
>
> It is bound to `<mouse-2>`.
>
> (anonymous E)
>
> Not documented.

I assume this is what is causing my issue, but it doesn't seem clear to me where this is coming from.

Comment: Does this also happen when you start emacs with `-Q`? It does not happen in my setup (emacs 25.1.50.2, org-version 8.2.10).

Comment: @Tobias with `-Q` it works as I want it to. See my update though.

Comment: A search for the binding delivers: [org-bullets.el](http://orgmode.org/w/?p=org-mode.git;a=blob_plain;f=contrib/lisp/org-bullets.el;hb=HEAD) If this is what hurts you see the documentation of `org-bullets-bullet-map`. They propertize the bullets with this: `(put-text-property (match-beginning 0)
         (match-end 0)
         'keymap
         org-bullets-bullet-map)`

Comment: @Tobias yep, that is it. The docs for `org-bullets-bullet-map` also mention of the behaviour: "Should this be undesirable, one can remove them with `(setcdr org-bullets-bullet-map nil)`" Which is exactly what I did, and it worked. How did you search the binding? I was not sure the best way to find where this was being defined. Also, you can post this as an answer if you want and I will accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [search for the binding](https://www.google.de/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=%28lambda+%28e%29+%28interactive+%22e%22%29+%28mouse-set-point+e%29+%28org-cycle%29%29&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=fVIBV_PFEfCP8Qe1tZeIDA) delivers: [org-bullets.el](http://orgmode.org/w/?p=org-mode.git;a=blob_plain;f=contrib/lisp/org-bullets.el;hb=HEAD).

See the documentation of `org-bullets-bullet-map`. There you find:

`Should this be undesirable, one can remove them with (setcdr org-bullets-bullet-map nil)`

They propertize the bullets with this:

```
(put-text-property (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0)
                   'keymap org-bullets-bullet-map)`
```